# looking for graphing app/software which can graph this equation

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I have an equation which makes a spiral that I want to print but none of the apps/sites I tried generate enough spiral curves. I want at least 11 curves.

I already tried desmos.com and mathstud.io - desmos stops at around 8 curves. The equation is 
[image-link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvBxe.png)

$$r=a.\theta^2-1+b.\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graphing Calculator 3D to accomplish this.

First, type down your equation and variables like this:

```
a=0.001
b=1
r=a*θ^2-1+b*θ
```

Then, change the default range of θ to go from `0` to `16pi`.

Here is the result I got:

[image]